# What font is used in this image?

Tags: fonts, graphics, truetype, visualization

Can someone identify the fonts used in the words "nature methods" in the following image?

[image: http://www.nature.com/nmeth/images/journal_header_v3.jpg]

I think that the word "nature" is in Times or Times New Roman (?) but can't figure out what font the word "methods" is in.  Any ideas?

Comment: ?? The serif font looks *nothing* like Times New Roman. It's in the Garamond/Sabon/Hoefler Text family, though I'm not sure exactly which font it is.

Comment: Best Dupe: [How can I identify fonts from an image?](http://superuser.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-identify-fonts-from-an-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/index.html) and got more than 30 [results](http://www.identifont.com/identify?13+methods+PWA+9M+97+31+23+F+39+DAN+PAF+G39+9J+9Z+L+M). If you have a better version of the image, you could try uploading it to [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).