# What is this font?

Tags: fonts, truetype

On the website insomniac.com, the logo "insomniac" what font is that? I've tried taking a screen shot and using whatthefont.com but the choices it gives me aren't 100% spot on. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Best Dupe: [How can I identify fonts from an image?](http://superuser.com/questions/17764/how-can-i-identify-fonts-from-an-image)

Answer (score 2):

Also try http://www.whatfontis.com/ and http://www.identifont.com/ . Looking at that font, I'd put money on it being custom made/identified. The c is probably just an adapted o for style.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to Red Rooster's Harry Heavy.