# Need some help in recognizing a font on the image

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop

[image]

Can't figure out, what kind of font is used here? Could somebody help?

Comment: Try some OCR software (such as Adobe FineReader and so on) to get the text out from image. But as I see  it's a russian text, try common russian fonts. And probably it's a payment check, so if you want to exactly know which font it uses, you can find that device and look in its specifications...

Comment: [This](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) might help

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/200597/what-is-this-font?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try making a smaller image and then try : http://www.whatfontis.com/

Use just one line, the clearest!  It usually works for me.