# Is there a program that can scan an image and tell you what font type it's using?

Tags: windows, fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Font recognition software](https://superuser.com/questions/17764/font-recognition-software)

Is there a program that can scan an image and tell you what font type it's using? Possibly by dragging a box around a sample for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of such program, but there is a [free service WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) that can do that for you. You simply upload your image and it identifies the font.

Please note that the identification is not 100% perfect, as many fonts are quite similar. If your text is big, and there are quite a few characters, it will be much better than based on few tiny letters.

Moreover, web-based tool is much more useful than desktop software since it can identify the fonts not installed on your computer (MyFonts has huge fonts library).

Answer (score 1):

Not a program, *per se*, but: [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) does what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Google Goggles on smartphones can sometimes also do this.